# No operating system found after installing ubuntu 13.10

Tags: boot, grub2, system-installation, 13.10, uefi

I successfully installed Ubuntu 13.10 to my Acer 4750G laptop but when I restart it, it gives me an error like:
Could not found: \EFI\BOOT\fallback.efi

I tried to use the boot-repair and it succeed but when I restart my laptop again, the it gives me the same error again.

Here is the url: http://paste.ubuntu.com/6424180

Please if you can help me I will really appreciate it.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Turn off Secure boot by changing `UEFI mode` to `Legacy mode` in bios and then try `boot-repair` disk.

Comment: I can't access bios and my windows 8 doesn't have a UEFI Firmware Settings. Is there another way to turn off secure boot? I have been looking for answers online but I can't find any working solution. Thanks

Comment: After this error `Could not found: \EFI\BOOT\fallback.efi` what was shown on the screen?

Comment: Try F10 OR F12,to enter into bios,or it may give you an option to choose which os is to boot.

Comment: After the error, it would say Operating System Not Found

Comment: When I press F12, it only show Secure Boot Enabled and then it will continue to load Windows 8

Comment: Since I installed Windows 8 in my laptop, I cannot access bios, I really want to disable secure boot. I tried removing CMOS/Bios battery but nothing happened.

Comment: see this page to turn off secure boot in acer laptops http://askubuntu.com/questions/285841/disabled-secure-boot-and-enabled-uefi-for-dual-boot-on-acer or http://community.acer.com/t5/Notebooks-Netbooks/How-do-I-disable-secure-boot-on-an-Aspire-V5-171/td-p/44003 or http://askubuntu.com/questions/285841/disabled-secure-boot-and-enabled-uefi-for-dual-boot-on-acer